# How update dropdownlist to default value

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, cascadingdropdown

I have 2 dropdownlist cascade.

I use MVVM.

user story:

1. select value from first DDL (automatically enable second DDL and push data)
2. select value from second DDL
3. click ADD (add value field in datasource in model)

it's work.

I need update first DDL to default value ("Select...") and automatically disable second DDL but first DDL is default..

How do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first DDL have ID = "myFirstDDL" .
Then

```
var firstDDL = $('#myFirstDDL').data('kendoDropDownList');// kendo object
firstDDL.dataSource.read(); // re-new data from Your Server - if you need this.
firstDDL.select(0);//update first DDL to default value ("Select...") and automatically disable second DDL
```